# Compare temporary table to actual table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have two tables in my script.

```
@varTable 
tableA
```

The first one being a variable table and the second one being the actual table in the database.  I created the temporary table exactly from the script, it has the same columns, types and sizes.

My script does some work to populate **@varTable**.

My goal is to insert all records in **@varTable** currently not in **tableA**, into **tableA**.

This is my SQL:

```
insert into [tableA] 
SELECT * FROM @varTable WHERE [columnA] NOT IN (SELECT [columnA] FROM [tableA]);
```

The select statement is always returning a blank statement.

If I separately view the tables, I am absolutely sure that **tableA** does NOT have data and that **@varTable** does.

Here's the part where it gets even more confusing.  I tested making another table variable called **@varTable2** and tested using that instead of the real table name (**tableA**) in the insert script; and it works perfectly fine.

So why is the select statement working for two table variables but not when I try to select into an actual table?

Comment: Are there any NULL values returned by the `NOT IN` subquery?  That will result in no rows qualifying the predicate.

Comment: Yeah, it turned out that was the cause.  thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will happen if `columnA` is ever `NULL`.  An easy fix is:

```
SELECT *
FROM @varTable
WHERE [columnA] NOT IN (SELECT a.[columnA] FROM [tableA] a WHERE a.columnA IS NOT NULL);
```

However, I recommend using `NOT EXISTS`.  It has the semantics that you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM @varTable vt
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM tableA a
                  WHERE a.columnA = vt.columnA);
```

In fact, I think I only use `NOT IN` when the list consists of constant expressions.

Comment: I'm still adapting to SQL, thanks a lot!  this was really bothering me for a while.